# If $f(x) = \frac {x^2-9}{x-3}$ and $g(x) = x+3$, then is $f=g$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

This one's a simple question...

Let $f,g : A→B$, where $A,B⊆R$ i.e both $f$ and $g$ are real functions and $f(x) = \dfrac {x^2-9}{x-3}$ and $g(x) = x+3$, then is $f=g$?

I've read that two functions are equal if their domain and co-domain are equal and their image for each input is equal.

in the case of $f$ and $g$, their domains and co-domains are equal to respectively $A$ and $B$

But the image of $3$ under $A$ is not defined as $\dfrac {x^2-9}{0}$ is not defined and its image under $B$ is $6$ as $3+3=6$, which are not equal.

So, in my opinion $f \neq g$.

This means that two functions need not be equal if one is the simplification of other, right?

And also, if two functions are equal, their range must be equal too, right?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Don't jump on the first given answer.

Comment: Note that they **are equal** if you force the domain of each to be $\mathbb R-\{3\}$. Domains are chosen or assumed.

Comment: I reached late to this one, but you seem to be correct. On the other hand, the accepted answer is wrong, because the "image for $3$" does not make sense for the function $f$, which is different from "the image of $3$ is not equal" because the second statement assumes that the image of $3$ exists, when it does not. Even though this is a small looking issue, in a simple subject like elementary set theory you must take objection to it.

Comment: The way the question is written, $f,g:A\to B$, you actually already forced the domain to be equal (they are both $A$). So unless you allow different domains, $f$ and $g$ *are* actually equal. For example, we could say $f=g$ as functions $\mathbb R\setmimus\{3\}\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: Oh yeah, I totally missed that, thanks for pointing out

Comment: By the way, my answer was wrong as well !

Comment: I finally want add, that $\tfrac{x^2-9}{0}$ is undefined, is a handwaving argument. It seems you evaluated $f$ in the denominator, but not in the numerator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The domain of $f$ is $A$. Because the expression $(x^2-9)/(x-3)$ is not defined at $x = 3$ (and because $f(x) = (x^2-9)/(x-3)$ for all $x \in A$ and because $f$ is a function to a subset of $\mathbb R$), $3$ cannot be an element of the domain $A$. So, $f$ and $g$ have the same domain, the same codomain, and take on the same value for all elements of the domain, and therefore $f = g$.

Comment: Thank You......

Answer (score 1):

These two functions differ because their *domains* differ. The first is $\mathbb R\setminus\{3\}$, while the second is $\mathbb R$.

It is not correct to say that the functions take "different values" at $x=3$.

Note that the *ranges* also differ. The first is $\mathbb R\setminus\{6\}$, while the second is $\mathbb R$.

---

**Update:**

This answer is wrong because the domain and range are *given* so they are implicitly equal. That common domain perforce does not contain $x=3$ and the functions are equal.

Comment: Thanks, good thing you edited your answer :)

Comment: @Rajdeep_Sindhu: yep, I misread the question, my bad. Yet another reason not to jump on the… second answer.

Comment: @Yves_Daoust No problem :)